# Which structure is grammatically correct

Tags: grammaticality

Which one of the following is grammatically correct?

> the three lesson unit
>
> the three lessons unit

Also mention whether the the correct structure is a dependent clause, independent clause or a phrase.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a matter of grammar. It sounds more like a question of whether your unit has 3 lessons or whether it is any number of lessons about something called "three lessons".

Answer (score 1):

In this kind of construction (I assume you're talking about a unit consisting of three lessons), the noun is in the singular, even though that may not seem logical. Also, a hyphen is typically, though not consistently, used to link the number and the noun. "The three-lesson unit", "[a 40-hour work week](https://www.themuse.com/advice/should-we-bring-back-the-40hour-work-week)", "[a seven-day diet](https://www.fitnessmagazine.com/weight-loss/plans/7-day/the-biggest-loser-7-day-diet-plan/)", etc.

Comment: What about an apostrophe? I mean The Three Lessons' Unit

Comment: That doesn't work. It means "the unit belonging to The Three Lessons". If an organization named "Three Lessons" donated a lot of money to a hospital, and the hospital built a new surgical unit from that money, they might call it the Three Lessons' Unit. But it doesn't mean what you were asking about.